# Overwrite documents with drag and drop

Tags: 2013, document-library, drag-and-drop

SharePoint 2013.

When I use drag and drop to add a new version of a document to a document library, I systematically get this message:

> A file named [file name here] already exists in this library. What would you like to do?

With two options: `Replace it` or `Don't upload`

Is there a way to get rid of this alert, and have `Replace it` as default behavior?

I am trying to get a behavior similar to older versions, where the `Overwrite existing file` option was checked by default.

Comment: Off topic, but this new default behavior was one of the most requested feature from my clients in 2010 ;)

Comment: @RobertLindgren sure, those who wanted overwrite by default didn't have to request it ;-) What we really want is to have the choice!

Comment: Hehe, you can never please them all ;) but I totally agree, it should be a property on the list